# How to disable accessibility in MATE flavour?

Tags: gnome, mate, accessibility

After a recent install of a gnome application to Ubuntu 19.04 MATE, an application I subsequently purged, I am left with accessibility features enabled. The panel has the icon, and in keyboard use I will occasionally trigger a prompt to enable an accessibility feature.

I have seen methods to remove the accessibility icon but I want to remove the accessibility feature entirely.

As a halfway, removing the icon would be good, but `/usr/share/gnome-shell/js/ui/panel.js` -- required for the solution most often offered -- does not exist on my system.

Comment: Does running `mate-at-properties` and changing settings in it helps?

Comment: @N0rbert The dialog has entries for accessibility but they are all disabled.  The mobility entry offers a dropdown that is stuck on "Onboard".  That looks like the problematic one, but I don't see a way of disabling it through this dialog.

Comment: @N0rbert Ah! After I purge `onboard`,  `mate-at-properties` offers the opportunity to disable keyboard triggers for accessibility features. This also removed the icon.

Comment: If the problem gets solved, I would suggest to add self-answer below :)

Comment: @N0rbert Okay I will do that if no-one else answers in the meantime. We have to wait a day or so before answering our own questions -- I believe that is the policy for this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This turned out to be a Onboard issue.

The installation of the gnome3 application included an installation of `Onboard`. This is a front end for accessibility features.

The purge of the application did not remove the installation of Onboard so I had to purge Onboard explicitly. Now the icon is gone, and I no longer have the accessibility dialog popping up when I do pause with my finger on the shift key -- as I am wont to do.